# RDLC - VS report( Reportviewer) - How to find out the remaining length of the page

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, report, rdlc, reportviewer

How to find out the remaining length/height of the page at the indicated point.

I need RDLC/vs Report expression formula please.

[image]

I need to know the height of the page from the arrow to the end of a page. (as shown in the picture)

Comment: You should edit your question and add what you have tried so far and what you know about a possible solution. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you're not sure what information might be missing.

Comment: @BreakBB my question is clear, I need to know the height of the page from the arrow to the end of a page.

Comment: [Mechanical Turk request detector triggered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Mechanical_Turk). "SO" is not a "we do all your coding for you" community.

Comment: why no one answer on **(RDLC / vs reports)** questions why??

Comment: Export the report to .pdf, print it, and use a ruler?  Have you researched any techniques or did you just expect SO to do the research and work for you?  Take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reporting-services-developer-documentation?view=sql-server-2017) and come back when you've attempted to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: @Steve-o169 I'm don't need that like this way, I need to know at the run time. I need know length remaining to use that, for other processes, bcoz I have subreports

Comment: I am don't need to export to excel

Comment: The easiest solution for this is to limit the amount of data produced by the tables so they'll fit as you need.  Not sure if there's any expression that measures your available space, but you'd have to look through the documentation I posted to know that for sure.

Comment: @Steve-o169, Can i know element height of a point, such as a textbox in report I need where it's exactly - inches or centimeters

Comment: You can set a specific height and set the textboxes `CanGrow` property to false.  That's about the closest I know of to getting what you want.

Comment: @Steve-o169 I have master reports that use 2 or more subreports. How I can make each subreport to start on a new page

Comment: I'm using everything in a list control, can help me?! it's possible or no, have any idea.!!

Comment: @Ian Preston can you help me too?!

Comment: [Check the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-page-break-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230669/inserting-a-page-break-into-an-ssrs-report)

Comment: thank @Steve-o169 but still not working.

Comment: You may just have to put in a lot of effort with fiddling around in the properties and with different control types.  I had a similar situation where I needed page breaks based on a set line count in three different tablixes and had to mess around with the report for weeks until I figured it out exactly as it was needed. Try putting the subreports in new rows in your list control, try putting everything in a tablix, or not in any type of control item.