# Page breaks in subreports are not being respected in autogenerated RDLC code

Tags: c#, rdlc

I have some C# code which generates some RDLC such as this as a subreport of another report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition">
  <Width>7.5in</Width>
  <Code>
  (some VB scripts go here)
  </Code>
  <rd:ReportID>REDACTED</rd:ReportID>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <Body>
    <Height>3in</Height>
    <ReportItems>
      <Rectangle Name="Zb2f2f8b4ff494d15bc6585b34efb7652">
        <Style>
          <Border />
        </Style>
        <Height>0.125in</Height>
        <Width>7.5in</Width>
        <Top>0.01in</Top>
        <Left>0in</Left>
        <KeepTogether>false</KeepTogether>
        <ReportItems>
            (one and a half godzillion report items go here)
        </ReportItems>
        <PageBreak>
          <BreakLocation>Start</BreakLocation>
        </PageBreak>
        <Bookmark>Zfe6b6d34b3e1409dadd5fd77a1acb08c</Bookmark>
      </Rectangle>
      <Rectangle Name="Zfe6b6d34b3e1409dadd5fd77a1acb08c">
        <Style>
          <Border />
        </Style>
        <Height>0.125in</Height>
        <Width>7.5in</Width>
        <Top>0.26in</Top>
        <Left>0in</Left>
        <KeepTogether>false</KeepTogether>
        <ReportItems>
            (seven to the 9001st power report items go here)
        </ReportItems>
        <Bookmark>Zfe6b6d34b3e1409dadd5fd77a1acb08c</Bookmark>
      </Rectangle>
    </ReportItems>
  </Body>
  <DataSets>
    (some data sets go here)
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <ReportParameters>
    <ReportParameter Name="Title">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Prompt>ReportParameter1</Prompt>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Nullable>true</Nullable>
      <DefaultValue>
        <Values>
          <Value>Events</Value>
        </Values>
      </DefaultValue>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="r19">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Prompt>ReportParameter1</Prompt>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Nullable>true</Nullable>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="EventFilter">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Prompt>ReportParameter1</Prompt>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Nullable>true</Nullable>
    </ReportParameter>
    <ReportParameter Name="r51">
      <DataType>String</DataType>
      <Prompt>ReportParameter1</Prompt>
      <AllowBlank>true</AllowBlank>
      <Nullable>true</Nullable>
    </ReportParameter>
  </ReportParameters>
  <Page>
    <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>
    <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>
    <LeftMargin>0.5in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>0.5in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
  </Page>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="RootModel">
      <rd:DataSourceID>ead9fb2d-33cb-4023-9052-e431eff63ba5</rd:DataSourceID>
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>System.Data.DataSet</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>/* Local Connection */</ConnectString>
      </ConnectionProperties>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <CodeModules>
    <CodeModule>REDACTED.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=REDACTED</CodeModule>
  </CodeModules>
</Report>
```

However the `<BreakLocation>` element is not being respected; the page breaks in the report are arbitrary rather than occurring before the specified section. Is there something special I need to do to make page breaks work in subreports?

edit: I added this as the last element in the `<ReportItems>` collection, to no avail:

```
<Rectangle Name="Zfdfe94b4111c481abc7df3ca2a2f4f92">
    <Height>0in</Height>
    <Width>0in</Width>
    <Top>0in</Top>
    <Left>0in</Left>
    <KeepTogether>false</KeepTogether>
    <PageBreak>
        <BreakLocation>End</BreakLocation>
    </PageBreak>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: What if to use `Between`, not a `Start` in `BreakLocation`?

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't seem to help...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362902/how-to-get-rid-of-blank-pages-in-pdf-exported-from-ssrs

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230669/inserting-a-page-break-into-an-ssrs-report), it should be possible to add breaks *after* sub reports with help of Rectangle at the bottom of each SubReport after all rendering objects. The "PageBreak" property should be set to "End". When the SubReport is finished, the Rectangle forces a page break.

Comment: Hmm. I tried this (code posted in question edit) but nothing seems to have happened. Might it help to share the entire report code, not just the subreport I'm having trouble with?